# How add parameters to a location redirect in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a redirect in our conf.erb file that looks like:

```
location  /primary/api/umpco/airplay/ {
    rewrite /primary/api/umpco/airplay/(.*)
    <%= @primary_config['umpcoairplay']['url'] %>/$1 permanent;
}
```

How would I modify this so that it would take a variable for "umpco".  Something along these lines but I am not certain of the syntax:

```
location  /primary/api/<% somevar />/airplay/ {
    rewrite /primary/api/<% somevar />/airplay/(.*)
    <%= @primary_config['<% somevar />airplay']['url'] %>/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Further explanation:  I need to capture the value of "umpco" in the first line, then use that value in the second and third line.

Comment: You can add a wildcard to a rewrite rule (http://serverfault.com/questions/259680/nginx-wild-card-alias-location-is-it-possible) but it won't be available to ruby. So to get what you want, you'd need to iterate through all of the `@primary_config` objects using ruby in your erb file and generate a rewrite rule for the url in each one.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
location /primary/api/<%= somevar %>/airplay/ {
    rewrite /primary/api/<%= somevar %>/airplay/(.*)
    <%= @primary_config["#{somevar}airplay"]["url"] %>/$1 permanent;
}
```

If `somevar` is `"umpco"` the third line will be equivalent to this:

```
<%= @primary_config["umpcoairplay"]["url"] %>/$1 permanent;
```

This assumes that the `@primary_config` hash has an `"umpcoairplay"` key.

Comment: Wouldn't the second reference also be {somevar} like:

Comment: What is the # symbol for on the third line?  Thanks!

Comment: The # is for string interpolation: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics

Comment: `#{...}` does string interpolation in Ruby. So if the variable `name` has the value `"eeejay"`, then `"Hello, #{name}!"` will evaluate to `"Hello, eeejay!"`

Comment: Can you take a look at my question again, I added a further explanation of the problem.  Thanks so much.